# Setting Attributes for Components in React not working

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm following a video course on React, and it is showing us the basics of creating a shopping cart that will eventually look something like this:

[image: shopping cart screenshot]

I am still early in the course. I am building a component and setting the attributes. Right now, it should just show "Zero" and have the word "Increment" on the button. The problem is, I cannot see the word "Zero" in the Chrome browser. Chrome shows that the word is there, though:

[image: my code screenshot]

Here is my React code for `counter.jsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

class Counter extends Component {
    state = {
        count: 0
    };
    styles = {
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    };
    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
                <span style={this.styles} className='badge badge-primary m-2'>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                <button className='btn btn-secondary btn-sm'>Increment</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    formatCount() {
        const { count } = this.state;
        return count === 0 ? 'Zero' : count;
    }
}
 
export default Counter;
```

It is called in `index.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Counter from './components/counter';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Counter />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The course has a forum, and I asked a question about this yesterday [>> HERE <<](https://forum.codewithmosh.com/t/react-components-6-setting-attributes/15520), but there has been no answer, and I cannot continue building the project with the 1st step not working.

*Can someone point out what it is that I did wrong?*

Also, I personally think that the `formatCount()` function should declare `count` as:

```js
    formatCount() {
        const { count } = this.state.count;
        return count === 0 ? 'Zero' : count;
    }
```

But, that makes it so that the text "Zero" no longer appears in the Chrome debugger. Why?

(I included the bootstrap tag because the index page uses bootstrap, and it could be doing something that is hiding my text)

Comment: Is there a chance a `font-family` is set somewhere and that font isnt actually available?

Comment: @AdamThomas, I don't see anything other than `fontSize` and `fontWeight`. Would bootstrap have something hidden in its code? I haven't used bootstrap much.

Comment: But you could be right. It looks white in Chrome's Styles tab. Isn't bootstrap supposed to color it in?

Comment: Try selecting the element with the text in chrome, then look at the "computed" tab in the css pane and then search "font-family" to see what the value is.

Comment: Ah yeh that'll be it

Comment: Likely some parent element has `color: white` and this is propogating.

Comment: @AdamThomas Thanks! If you want the answer, put it down and I'll accept it.